# Deducing tensorial structure of a tensor

Tags: tensors, semi-riemannian-geometry

Consider an expression of the following form:

$$I^{\mu\nu}(r) = \int d^{3}k\ \ d^{3}l\ \ \delta^{4}(r-k-l)\ (g^{\mu\nu}k\cdot{l}+k^{\nu}k^{\mu}-k^{\mu}l^{\nu})$$

$I^{\mu\nu}$ must be of the form

$$I^{\mu\nu}(r) = Ar^{\mu}r^{\nu} + B\eta^{\mu\nu},$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

---

How can you determine this tensorial form of $I^{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: Is this correct? I don't see the index $\mu$.

Comment: question edited to take into account your comment